# How to have else statement return remaining values?

Tags: sql

I have a list of values I want to a case when statement to give the values new names:

**Item**

```
Apple
Orange
Cheese
Grapes
Garlic
```

Say I do a statement where I say `CASE WHEN Item in('Apple','Orange','Grapes') THEN 'Fruit' ELSE [Return Remaining Values]`

Essentially I'm trying to have my else statement return everything the remaining values of everything I didn't list a condition for.

So I want my SQL query to return:

```
Fruit
Cheese
Garlic
```

As a result

```
CASE WHEN Item in('Apple','Orange','Grapes') THEN 'Fruit' ELSE [Return Ramining Values]
```

Result:

```
Fruit
Cheese
Garlic
```

Comment: CASE WHEN Item in('Apple','Orange','Grapes') THEN 'Fruit' ELSE Item

Comment: keep in mind, this will return a row for each row in your data set, not just 3 like in your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN Item in('Apple','Orange','Grapes') THEN 'Fruit' ELSE Item End
```